# Alternative way to scp/cp files to remote server with wildcard target path

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell-script, scp

I am trying to copy a single file from local server to a list of servers described in servers.txt. The target path is something like /local/opt/path1/sub/*/lib/file.jar

the * may match any folder there.

```
 ls -ltrh  /local/opt/path1/sub/*/lib/file.jar

-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 538K Jan 31  2011 /local/opt/path1/sub/production/lib/file.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 538K Jan 31  2011 /local/opt/path1/sub/default/lib/file.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 538K Jan 31  2011 /local/opt/path1/sub/all/lib/file.jar
```

But if I try it like

```
for i in `cat servers.txt` do scp file.jar user@$i: /local/opt/path1/sub/*/lib/; done
```

It will show an error like ambiguous target. After some googling, I understood multiple targets are not supported for cp or its variants like scp. Now I have an idea to list the folders first using find command.

find command will be like

```
find /local/opt/path1/sub/ -name file.jar
```

But how to implement it in my script ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
for i in `cat servers.txt` do scp file.jar user@$i: /local/opt/path1/sub/*/lib/; done
```

to

```
for i in `cat servers.txt` do scp file.jar user@$i:/local/opt/path1/sub/*/lib/; done
```

Remove the space between `user@$i:` and `/local/opt/path1/sub/*/lib/`